# Can't understand the recursive function solution

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to learn about algorithms and recursion and stumbled upon the following code online. I understand how the function prints 321 but I am confused as to why it prints 123. I tried running the code on https://pythontutor.com but didn't understand why the second print statement didn't execute in any of the cases until it hit the base case. Thanks for helping.

```
# demonstrate working of
# recursion
 
 
def printFun(test):
 
    if (test < 1):
        return
    else:
 
        print(test, end=" ")
        printFun(test-1)  # statement 2
        print(test, end=" ")
        return
 
# Driver Code
test = 3
printFun(test)
```

Output is 3 2 1 1 2 3

Comment: Did you try solving it by hand? Using a pencil/pen and a piece of paper really helps in understanding recursion. Just start with small values of arguments and then it's easy to understand how it generalizes to bigger ones.

Comment: You do see that the function prints `test` *twice*, once before the recursive call, and once after.

Comment: I do see the two print statements but like I said I still don't understand why it prints 1 2 3 after printing 3 2 1

Comment: It may be a good idea to download an IDE (you can select any modern free IDE, I suggest you to try PyCharm, it has a free community version) put a breakpoint on the `print` line and debug your program step by step. The approach with paper and pen is good too, as it is important to understand how code works without running it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key part of this code is right here:

```
    print(test, end=" ")
    printFun(test-1)  # statement 2
    print(test, end=" ")
    return
```

First, the code prints out the numbers in descending order (3,2,1):

After the first:

```
print(test, end=" ")
```

The value of `test` begins to decrement by 1 each time. Until it reaches `0`, it will continue the cycle of decreasing. Once it reaches `0`, the code runs the second:

```
print(test, end=" ")
```

This time it will be in ascending order since it starts from 1 and goes up to 3.

This means that it will print 3 2 1 and then 1 2 3:

```
3 2 1 1 2 3
```

[image]

Let me know if you have any other questions!! It's great that you're asking questions about topics as difficult as recursion; it'll help you understand them better :)

Comment: Thanks for your explanation @Aniketh Malyala. But I still don't understand why does the second print statement not run until test hits test reaches 0 and why it goes up in ascending order after that

Comment: So after the first print statement runs, the recursion occurs with printFun(test-1). This means that the print statement after that will not occur until the recursion ends. Let me update the image real quick.

Comment: I understand now, thanks so much for answering.

Comment: I’m happy I could help :))